# Generating a form for a parent when presented with a subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here's my data models

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Landlord < Person
end
```

and I'd like be able to use my People controller to update both Landlords and People.  So here's my view:

```
- form_for :person, @person, :url => {:action => "update"} do |f|
  ...blah blah fields
```

where `@person` is either a Person or a Landlord but the html generated is as follows:

```
<form action="/people/1" method="post">
```

Can anybody shed some light as to why this is I was expecting the html to be

```
<form action="/people/1" method="put">
```

FWIW this is 2.3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using resourceful routes? You should be, that way you can use:

```
- form_for @person.becomes(Person) do |f|
  = f.field :attribute
```

`becomes` makes your instance appear to be the class you pass in as the 1st argument, which Rails then uses to identify and determine which controller to send it to:

```
@landlord.becomes(Person) # => Rails will send this to /people
```

This also works in other aspects of Rails:

```
render @person.becomes(Landlord)
link_to @landlord.becomes(Person)
```

Comment: I had no idea this existed.  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that rails makes all form methods POST, but passes it's own _method parameter that is a PUT, POST or DELETE request. You can usually see it as a hidden field right inside the form in the HTML, it will look like this for your form:

```
<input type='hidden' name='_method' value='put' />
```